# setxkbmap il and then setxkbmap us: How to switch back keyboad layout to English after changing keyboard layout to some other language

Tags: freebsd, keyboard-layout, xkb

I do this `setxkbmap il` on my `xterm` and then do my stuff in my local language layout. When done, I want to switch back to English layout with `setxkbmap us` but I cannot type English in my `xterm`. What should I do?

Comment: If you're actually using **xterm**, you could make a function-key definition that sends the command for switching back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With xterm, you could use the translations resource to assign a string (such as "setxkbmap us") to a function-key.  Doing that bypasses most of the keyboard problems, as well as issues with compose and special characters.

Something like this in your `$HOME/.Xdefaults` would assign the command to <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
*VT100*translations:    #override \n\
        Ctrl Shift <Key>F1: string("setxkbmap us") string(0xa) \n
```

Further reading: [Key Bindings](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-KEY-BINDINGS) in the xterm manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use alias for that. Well, I tried it in terminator, not in `xterm`, but it may work there as well.

I use Cyrillic and Greek fonts in this example, but you can find solution in whatever keyboard map you use.

```
alias сша="setxkbmap us"
alias ηπα="setxkbmap us"
```

Putting it to the `~/.bashrc` file makes it available later.